# Wordpress permalink, show a product catagory page on a normal WP page

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I'm not sure if I'm having a bad brain day but I am going round in circles with something I know is so simple. As a note, I am pretty new to developing in WordPress so apologies if it genuinely is something so simple.

Essentially I am needing to have a page (example.com/gear) show the exact same page as the category page for gear (example.com/product_catagory/gear).

Is there a way for the permalink to show the product category page without changing the permalink? Would it be better practice to use something like `is_page( 'gear' );` and then create a partial to show category products? Or is there something so much simpler than I can look into using?

I am not wanting to change the permalinks for product_catagoy I just want a new page to show a product category page (gear).

Thanks for your help

Eric

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin like WP Show Posts to create a shortcode for that taxonomy on your gear page.